# store parameter in @connect decorator callback

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new to React+Redux. I am confused why the redux state objects are not exposed directly to store but through the store.userReducer.

This is my connect decorator

```
 @connect((store) => {

 return {
   users: store.userReducer.users
//users: store.users
    }
})
```

This is the combineReducers

```
import {combineReducers} from "redux";

import userReducer from "./usersReducer";

export default combineReducers({
  userReducer
})
```

This is the relevant portion of userReducer

```
export default function reducer(state={
users:[],
fetching: false,
fetched: false,
error: null
}, action){
switch (action.type) {
  case "FETCH_USERS":{
  return {...state, fetching: true}
 }
```

This is the portion of the store

```
const middleware = applyMiddleware(promise(),thunk);
export default createStore(reducers,middleware);
```

Comment: the key you pass to `combineReducers` is the one that's on the store. and you're passing `userReducer: userReducer`

Comment: Yeah.......right.......I missed that in the docs.Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.I was thinking about some other obscure bugs...haha